# Using eclipse to program Pong

Tags: java, eclipse, pong

I am currently trying to teach myself to code in Java and I am using eclipse and I had a tutorial for creating pong but some how it has gone missing. The only part I am having trouble with is finishing the ball class. I have got it to render and appears correctly in the window but doesn't actually do anything it simply remains stationary. This is because I have no idea what code I need and all the google searches have resulted in nothing but frustration at code that does not work.

This is all I have in the ball class so far.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Ball extends Entity {

public Ball(int x, int y, Color color) {
    super(x, y, color);
    this.width = 15;
    this.height = 15;
    int yspeed = 1;
    int xspeed = 2;
}

public void render( Graphics g ) {
    super.render( g );
}




public void update() {
    if (y <= 0) {
        y = 0;
    }

    if (y >= window.HEIGHT - height - 32 ) {
        y = window.HEIGHT - height -32;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need some code in your update function to change the ball position (eg based on its velocity)

Answer (score 3):

Your ball class looks good so far what you have written (or copied from the tutorial). You're missing the code which puts 'life' in there, e.g. which makes the ball move. You have some fields like `xspeed` and `yspeed`, but no code to actually apply the delta from one time unit to another. The (I hope) periodically called `update()` method should apply both values to the `x` and `y` fields:

```
public void update() {
    x += xspeed;
    y += yspeed;

    if (y <= 0) {
        y = 0;
    }

    if (y >= window.HEIGHT - height - 32 ) {
        y = window.HEIGHT - height -32;
    }
}
```

That is what you need for the `update` part. 
The next big thing is to implement the logic what happens when the ball hit's a wall or paddle. For such an event you need to manipulate the `xspeed` and `yspeed` variables.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious step would be:

```
public void update() {
    x += xspeed;
    y += yspeed;

    if (y <= 0) {
        y = 0;
    }

    if (y >= window.HEIGHT - height - 32 ) {
        y = window.HEIGHT - height -32;
    }

    // TODO: Code to change the direction of the ball (i.e. xspeed and yspeed)
    // when it hits a wall or paddle.
}
```

And you must not forget to call `update()` before you call `render()`.